# Change Control MousePosition displayProjection

Tags: openlayers-2

I added mouse control on the map with Lat/Long as display projection.
I added a dropbox on the map for the user to choose a coordinate system (3 choices).
Depending on the selection, I would like to change the displayed coordinates. What I'm missing is the syntax to do that.

This is my initial coordinate system:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({displayProjection: 'EPSG:4326'}));
```

If the choice is EPSG:32187, I tried to change it:

```
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32187") });

OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({displayProjection: 'EPSG:32187'});

map.displayProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32187"); 

map.MousePosition = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32187");
```

Nothing works.

The only thing it worked is if I add another `MousePosition` control:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({displayProjection: 'EPSG:32187'}));
```

But that they are on on top of the other and I would like to reuse the existing Mouse control.

Answer (score 1):

I ended by removing the MousePosition Control and adding a new one
Not the most elegant solution but works

I'm still wondering about possibility of reusing existing controls